# Loan money circulation?

Tags: microeconomics, mathematical-economics, financial-economics, adjustment-costs, payment-system

I have a hypothetical situation and couple of such questions.
Imagine a situation like this:
You need 1000€ a month in order to survive.
There are three loan providers you can borrow the amount of 1000€ for a month with a fee of 1€ a month (you're always repaying money on time).

1. I borrow money from the first loan provider.
2. I spend the money.
3. I borrow money from second to repay the first.
4. I now owe money only to the second provider.
5. I borrow money from the third.
6. I spend the money.
7. I borrow money from first to repay the second.

And so on and so on, you can see the pattern. It's maybe a stupid question but could loan circulation work as a way of earning monthly money.

Comment: This doesnt appear to be a strict homework question to me. But yes, it is very specific - does the question need to be this specific?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be too narrow to be useful for future visitors

Answer (score 0):

This reminds me of the **Ponzi Scheme**: A Ponzi scheme is a fraudulent investment operation where the operator, an individual or organization, pays returns to its investors from new capital paid to the operators by new investors, rather than from profit earned by the operator. Operators of Ponzi schemes usually entice new investors by offering higher returns than other investments, in the form of short-term returns that are either abnormally high or unusually consistent (source [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ponzi_scheme) with numerous examples).

Answer (score 0):

There is no "and so on" in your series. By the end of step 7, you owe 1000 Euro to the both the first and third lenders, and would therefore have to borrow at least 2000 Euro from the second— which according to the way you framed the question, you can't— to repay them. You can view this as a strong hint that no amount or pattern of borrowing will ever result in income, only debt.